# Progress indicator around square view

Tags: android, animation, progress-indicator

I'm trying to achieve [this](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Tubitv/TubiLoadingView/master/app/src/main/res/raw/github_img.gif) animation effect on square view. It should be an indeterminate progress indicator.

It should look like image [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MMqE6.png)

I know I can do this through a set of images (create GIF) but I need to create this feature in code.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987112/2252830

Comment: @pskink this was helpful, only gradient is missing from your example.

Comment: simply because OP didnt want any gradient - he wanted just solid color

Answer (score 0):

You can use [square_progress_indicator](https://pub.dev/packages/square_progress_indicator) package, here is example:

```
            SquareProgressIndicator(
              value: _value,
              color: Colors.grey,
              strokeWidth: 2,
              child: Image.asset('android_logo.png'),
            ),
```