# How to create custom shaped progress bar with range highlighting on Android?

Tags: android, android-layout, opengl-es, android-canvas

I understand this can be a broad question for SO, however I will try to define some starting ideas to limit its scope, making it useful for other users creating complex UI on Android and other platforms.

### The Component

My target is to create the following UI component:
[image: desired component]

Its shape consists of a square with rounded edges with a gap at 12 o'clock. The background where the highlighted sections seats have a solid color. While the highlighted sections have a different color follow the same shape as the background. All the highlighted sections should have rounded edges.

### Implementation Ideas

### Android canvas default shapes

This was the naivest idea I got, to construct the shape using the Canvas.draw{Circle,Line,Arc} calls like shown bellow.

[image]

However am not comfortable with such solution because it is not reusable and is going to be quite complex once we can have an arbitrary number of highlighted sections.

### Masked layers

The idea would the to draw the base shape using Android canvas drawing calls twice, one version with the background color and the second with the highlighted color in two different bitmaps, and then merge then using a mask that selects the highlighted areas. Like in the image bellow:
[image]
This solution seems more elegant, however I am not able to get the highlighted areas with rounded edges.

### OpenGL color matching

As an alternative solution to using Android canvas draw calls we could use OpenGL. The idea would be to have the base shape draw on an illustration software with the following color properties:

[image]

Then uploading it as a texture to OpenGL and using a shader to do color and saturation matching for drawing the different highlighted sections.

So far this is my favorite idea. It works with any shape and I can outsource my work to the designer ;~) However I was not able to find anyone doing something like that.

Would be great both to receive solutions not mentioned in this question or any extra material related to the ideas above.

Comment: see https://stackoverflow.com/a/44987112/2252830 , your job is to create your `Path src` - now it is a rounded hexagon

Comment: and of course if you want 4 highlighted sections you need 4 `Path`s segments (`Path segment = new Path();`)

Comment: I would need an arbitrary number of segments, therefore a loop could handle that.

Comment: sure, loop and some sort of list/array of `Path`s

Comment: or even better a list of class holding a `Path segment`, `float startOffset` and `float endOffset`

Comment: Yep, that is a great solution. If you write an answer with that solution I am happy to accept it.

Comment: oh it is so similar to the link i posted in my first comment so the implementation to match your needs will be quite easy and i am pretty sure you will manage to do that by yourself

Comment: For sure, it was just for the sake of this question. However I am implementing it already, it is going great. Thanks!